CashApp Payment Method Not Rendering in Django with Adyen Integration
I'm trying to integrate Adyen's payment methods (including CashApp) into my Django web application, but the CashApp payment method isn't rendering on the front end. Instead, I receive the following error:
ERROR Error during initialization ERROR: Error during initialization
at e.<anonymous> (https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/sdk/5.68.0/adyen.js:1:460538)
at P (https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/sdk/5.68.0/adyen.js:1:41524)
at Generator.<anonymous> (https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/sdk/5.68.0/adyen.js:1:42844)

This same code is rendering the card payment gateway but not working on the cashapp.
My html Code:
Where is used adyen sdk=5.68.0 version. Version greater than 5.69.0 gives different error that AdyenCheckout is not defined I don't know how to solve that too.

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<meta name="vtokvaldat" content="{{ csrf_token }}">


<!-- Adyen css from TEST environment (change to live for production)-->
<link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/sdk/5.68.0/adyen.css"
        integrity="sha384-gpOE6R0K50VgXe6u/pyjzkKl4Kr8hXu93KUCTmC4LqbO9mpoGUYsrmeVLcp2eejn"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="payment-page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="payment-container">

            <div id="component" class="payment">
                <!-- Component will be rendered here -->
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    {% csrf_token %}
</div>

<!-- Adyen JS from TEST environment (change to live for production)-->
<script src="https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/sdk/5.68.0/adyen.js"
        integrity="sha384-U9GX6Oa3W024049K86PYG36/jHjkvUqsRd8Y9cF1CmB92sm4tnjxDXF/tkdcsk6k"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


{{ client_key|json_script:"client-key" }}
{{ method|json_script:"integration-type" }}
<script>
    const clientKey = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('client-key').innerHTML);
    const type = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('integration-type').innerHTML);

    // Used to finalize a checkout call in case of redirect
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const sessionId = urlParams.get('sessionId'); // Unique identifier for the payment session
    const redirectResult = urlParams.get('redirectResult');


    // Start the Checkout workflow
    async function startCheckout() {
        try {
            // Init Sessions
            const checkoutSessionResponse = await callServer({% url 'sessions' %});
            // Create AdyenCheckout using Sessions response
            const checkout = await createAdyenCheckout(checkoutSessionResponse)
            // Create an instance of Drop-in and mount it to the container you created.
            const dropinComponent = checkout.create(type).mount("#component");  // pass DIV id where component must be rendered
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            alert("Error occurred. Look at console for details");
        }
    }

    // Some payment methods use redirects. This is where we finalize the operation
    async function finalizeCheckout() {
        try {
            // Create AdyenCheckout re-using existing Session
            const checkout = await createAdyenCheckout({id: sessionId});

            // Submit the extracted redirectResult (to trigger onPaymentCompleted(result, component) handler)
            checkout.submitDetails({details: {redirectResult}});
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            alert("Error occurred. Look at console for details");
        }
    }

    function getCSRFToken() {
        const token = document.querySelector('meta[name="vtokvaldat"]').getAttribute('content');
        return token;
    }

    async function createAdyenCheckout(session) {

        const configuration = {
            clientKey,
            locale: "en-US",
            environment: "test",  // change to live for production
            showPayButton: true,
            session: session,
            paymentMethodsConfiguration: {
                ideal: {
                    showImage: true
                },
                card: {
                    hasHolderName: true,
                    holderNameRequired: true,
                    name: "Credit or debit card",
                    countryCode: "US"
                },
                paypal: {
                    environment: "test",
                    countryCode: "US"   // Only needed for test. This will be automatically retrieved when you are in production.
                },
                cashapp: {
                    environment: "test",
                    countryCode: "US",
                    referenceId: "5465456435156",
                    showsStorePaymentMethodField: true,
                    storePaymentMethod: true
                }
            },
            onPaymentCompleted: (result, component) => {
                console.info(result, component);
                handleServerResponse(result, component);
            },
            onError: (error, component) => {
                console.error(error.name, error.message, error.stack, component);
            }
        };

        return new AdyenCheckout(configuration);
    }


    // Calls your server endpoints
    async function callServer(url, data) {
        const res = await fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            body: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : "",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "X-CSRFToken": getCSRFToken()
            }
        });
        return await res.json();
    }

    // Handles responses sent from your server to the client
    function handleServerResponse(res, component) {
        if (res.action) {
            component.handleAction(res.action);
        } else {
            switch (res.resultCode) {
                case "Authorised":
                    window.location.href = "{% url 'success' %}";
                    break;
                case "Pending":
                case "Received":
                    window.location.href = "/pending";
                    break;
                case "Refused":
                    window.location.href = "{% url 'failed' %}";
                    break;
                default:
                    window.location.href = "{% url 'error' %}";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!sessionId) {
        startCheckout();
    }
    else {
        // existing session: complete Checkout
        finalizeCheckout();
    }
</script>

django view.py file:
import json
import uuid
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
import Adyen

def adyen_sessions(request):
    # payments = ["card", "cashapp", "paypal"]
    session_response = {
        'client_key': settings.ADYEN_CLIENT_KEY,
        'method': 'cashapp'
    }
    return render(request, 'component.html', context=session_response)

def sessions(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        adyen = Adyen.Adyen()
        adyen.payment.client.xapikey = settings.ADYEN_API_KEY
        adyen.payment.client.platform = settings.ADYEN_ENVIRONMENT
        adyen.payment.client.merchant_account = settings.ADYEN_MERCHANT_ACCOUNT

        request_data = {
            'amount': {
                "value": 1900,  # amount in minor units
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            'reference': f"Reference {uuid.uuid4()}",
            'returnUrl': f"{request.build_absolute_uri('/redirect?shopperOrder=myRef')}",
            'countryCode': "US",
            'channel': 'Web',
            "recurringProcessingModel": "CardOnFile",
            "storePaymentMethodMode": "askForConsent",
            'lineItems': [
                {
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "amountIncludingTax": 5000,
                    "description": "Sunglasses"
                },
                {
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "amountIncludingTax": 5000,
                    "description": "Headphones"
                }
            ],
            'merchantAccount': settings.ADYEN_MERCHANT_ACCOUNT,
        }
        result = adyen.checkout.payments_api.sessions(request_data)
        data = json.loads(result.raw_response)
        print("/sessions response:\n" + data.__str__())
        return JsonResponse(data, status=200, safe=False)

def redirect_view(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def success(request):
    return render(request, 'checkout-success.html')

def failed(request):
    return render(request, 'checkout-failed.html')

def error(request):
    return render(request, 'error.html')

django urls.py:
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.adyen_sessions, name='adyen_sessions'),
    path('redirect/', views.redirect_view, name='redirect_view'),
    path('sessions/', views.sessions, name='sessions'),
    path('success/', views.success, name='success'),
    path('failed/', views.failed, name='failed'),
    path('error/', views.error, name='error'),
]

ERROR Image:


According to the Adyen Documentation for CashApp you have to include the following two parameters in your request:

    "storePaymentMethodMode": "askForConsent"
    "recurringProcessingModel": "CardOnFile" 

I'd also ensure that startCheckout(..) is called on the page. I don't see the startCheckout(..) being called in the inserted snippet.

Here's my version of the code, I've started with the Python-integration-example on Github and modified it slightly:
// sessions.py (backend)

def adyen_sessions(host_url):
    adyen = Adyen.Adyen()
    adyen.payment.client.xapikey = get_adyen_api_key()
    adyen.payment.client.platform = "test"
    adyen.payment.client.merchant_account = get_adyen_merchant_account()

    request_data = {
        'amount': {
            'value': 1900, 
            'currency': 'USD'
        },
        'reference': f"Reference {uuid.uuid4()}",
        'returnUrl': f"{host_url}/redirect?shopperOrder=myRef", # Modify this so it will return the user to your specific page when redirected
        'countryCode': 'US',
        'channel': 'Web',
        'recurringProcessingModel': 'CardOnFile',
        'storePaymentMethodMode': 'askForConsent',
        
        'lineItems': [
            {
                'quantity': 1,
                'amountIncludingTax': 5000,
                'description': 'Sunglasses'
            },
            {
                'quantity': 1,
                'amountIncludingTax': 5000,
                'description': 'Headphones'
            }
        ],
        'merchantAccount': get_adyen_merchant_account(),
    }
    result = adyen.checkout.payments_api.sessions(request_data)
    formatted_response = json.dumps((json.loads(result.raw_response)))
    print("/sessions response:\n" + formatted_response)
    return formatted_response

// In config.py (added 'cashapp' for components)
def get_supported_integration():
    return ['dropin', 'card', 'ideal', 'klarna', 'directEbanking', 'alipay', 'boletobancario',
            'sepadirectdebit', 'dotpay', 'giropay', 'ach', 'paypal', 'applepay',
            'klarna_paynow', 'klarna', 'klarna_account', 'cashapp']


// Frontend
const clientKey = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('client-key').innerHTML);
const type = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('integration-type').innerHTML);

// Used to finalize a checkout call in case of redirect
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const sessionId = urlParams.get('sessionId'); // Unique identifier for the payment session
const redirectResult = urlParams.get('redirectResult');


// Start the Checkout workflow
async function startCheckout() {
    try {
        // Init Sessions
        const checkoutSessionResponse = await callServer("/api/sessions?type=" + type);

        // Create AdyenCheckout using Sessions response
        const checkout = await createAdyenCheckout(checkoutSessionResponse)

        // Create an instance of Drop-in and mount it to the container you created.
        const dropinComponent = checkout.create(type).mount("#component");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        alert("Error occurred. Look at console for details");
    }
}

// Some payment methods use redirects. This is where we finalize the operation
async function finalizeCheckout() {
    try {
        // Create AdyenCheckout re-using existing Session
        const checkout = await createAdyenCheckout({id: sessionId});

        // Submit the extracted redirectResult (to trigger onPaymentCompleted(result, component) handler)
        checkout.submitDetails({details: {redirectResult}});
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        alert("Error occurred. Look at console for details");
    }
}

function getCSRFToken() {
    const token = "token";// document.querySelector('meta[name="vtokvaldat"]').getAttribute('content'); // Our example doesn't have this field, hence why I left this one out for now
    return token;
}

async function createAdyenCheckout(session) {

    const configuration = {
        clientKey,
        locale: "en-US",
        environment: "test",  // change to live for production
        showPayButton: true,
        session: session,
        paymentMethodsConfiguration: {
            ideal: {
                showImage: true
            },
            card: {
                hasHolderName: true,
                holderNameRequired: true,
                name: "Credit or debit card",
                countryCode: "US"
            },
            paypal: {
                environment: "test",
                countryCode: "US"   // Only needed for test. This will be automatically retrieved when you are in production.
            },
            cashapp: {
                environment: "test",
                countryCode: "US",
                referenceId: "5465456435156",
                showsStorePaymentMethodField: true,
                storePaymentMethod: true,
                style: { button: { shape: 'semiround' } }
            }
        },
        onPaymentCompleted: (result, component) => {
            console.info(result, component);
            handleServerResponse(result, component);
        },
        onError: (error, component) => {
            console.error(error.name, error.message, error.stack, component);
        }
    };

    return new AdyenCheckout(configuration);
}


// Calls your server endpoints
async function callServer(url, data) {
    const res = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : "",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-CSRFToken": getCSRFToken()
        }
    });
    return await res.json();
}

// Handles responses sent from your server to the client
function handleServerResponse(res, component) {
    if (res.action) {
        component.handleAction(res.action);
    } else {
        switch (res.resultCode) {
            case "Authorised":
                window.location.href = "{% url 'success' %}";
                break;
            case "Pending":
            case "Received":
                window.location.href = "/pending";
                break;
            case "Refused":
                window.location.href = "{% url 'failed' %}";
                break;
            default:
                window.location.href = "{% url 'error' %}";
                break;
        }
    }
}

if (!sessionId) {
    startCheckout();
}
else {
    // existing session: complete Checkout
    finalizeCheckout();
}


Hope this helped!

Thanks, Kwok He. I have added the missing field, but it still gives an error. I have also updated the question to include detailed JavaScript and Python code, which should help in understanding the issue better. Please review it once more. The card payment is rendering correctly, and PayPal is working fine, but CashApp is not rendering. I have already copied my code from the Flask repository you mentioned, but CashApp is still not working. The CashApp button gets rendered if we downgrade the SDK to version 5.40.0, but in that SDK, CashApp is not supported and produces different errors

Could you show me the snippets that you're using and which error you're getting?

I'd double check 3 things according to the docs  -> [1] Ensure Cash App is enabled in your Customer Area. [2] To ask the shopper if they want to store their Cash App Pay details, set enableStoreDetails to true when you configure Cash App Pay. This shows a toggle that lets the shopper save their payment details.
And [3] to store the shopper's payment details without asking if they want to, set storePaymentMethodMode in your /sessions request and set storePaymentMethod to true in the configuration object.

I have already tried all these steps, but it still gives an error. The API returns a response, but an initialization error occurs when we call the .mount() function on the Drop-in component in JavaScript.

If you're getting a response, it means the backend python is (most likely) working. Can you show a minimal frontend (.js) code of how you're mounting the component?

I have updated the code in question, showing the exact JavaScript code I am using. I have also attached screenshots of the error messages.

I've updated my code based on your example. I was able to render both the Adyen.drop-in (type="dropin") and component (type="cashapp"). You have to pass the full session response to your drop-in/component

Yes, it is working on Flask. I have tried the same code in Django, but it is not working there, while the same code works in Flask. I am unable to solve it in Django.

I have added my complete code to the question. For Django, you can try it yourself to see if it works for you.

I have solved the issue; it was quite easy to fix. I don't understand why it was triggering the error. I was using the 127.0.0.1:8000 URL to open the website, and I was only getting an error on CashApp. When I switched the URL to localhost:8000, CashApp rendered correctly. I also added both URLs to the Adyen origin, but I still don't understand why it was only causing an issue with CashApp. Nevertheless, thank you for helping, Kwok He.
